# c3p0 managed by Spring

Tags: spring, c3p0

Do anyone know a way to make:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator
```

using Spring and not a c3p0.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the following bean:

```
<bean id="sysProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetClass"><value>java.lang.System</value></property>
  <property name="targetMethod"><value>setProperty</value></property>
  <property name="arguments">
    <list>
      <value>com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator</value>
      <value>com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Your data source bean definition should then include a `depends-on` attribute like the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" depends-on="sysProps">
```